# Is there any way to access a docker (nginx) container via a local url like http://mydomain.dev?

Tags: php, networking, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm basically using the setup from: https://github.com/wouterds/docker (but not using mysql)

The following is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.10.2
    ports:
        - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ~/server/firebase-test/code:/code
    links:
        - php
    depends_on:
        - php

php:
    build: php
    expose:
        - 9000
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./php/conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
        - ~/server/firebase-test/code:/code
```

It works correctly if I go to http://localhost

But I'm using this container setup to develop a bunch of different sites. Sometimes I need them running at the same time so they both try to use the localhost url which isn't possible. Is there a way for me to manually have them referenced by something like http://websitename.dev or http://[container-name].dev locally? Does docker-compose auto generated some kind of network mapping that I can use to access the container instead of http://localhost?

Pretty new to Docker so I'm a little lost and googling for the last hour didn't result in much other than a tool called "docker-hostmanager" but it doesn't work with the v2 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to configure nginx to do this using the server_name directive:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: But that would map the domain *inside* docker. I need it accessible *outside* of docker. As in, the docker container acts as the server and my host OS is able to access it via a browser like any other site in the world.

Comment: I believe the container would still be accessible from the host because the nginx port (80) is mapped from container to host in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: You might also need to add an entry to the hosts file on your host OS that maps nginx server_name to localhost IP, .e.g., ```127.0.0.1     example.org```